# Pass String Array from one fragment to another

Tags: android, listview, interface

I am Using one String [] to display in ListView of fragmentone and pass String[] to fragmentTwo which has listView. my tried Codes below,

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ListInterface {

private FragmentOne fragmentOne;
private FragmentTwo fragmentTwo;

@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
    setContentView (R.layout.activity_main);

     fragmentOne = new FragmentOne ();
    fragmentTwo = new FragmentTwo ();

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager ();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction ();

    fragmentTransaction.add (R.id.frame_one,fragmentOne);
    fragmentTransaction.add (R.id.frame_two , fragmentTwo);

    fragmentTransaction.commit ();
}

@Override
public void getValue (String[] s) {
    fragmentTwo.setValue (s);
}}
```

FragmentOne:

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {

private ListView listView;
private ListInterface listInterface;
String [] listData = {"Dhana","Rahul","Strobs","Uday","Selvi"};

@Override
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate (R.layout.fragment_one,container,false);
    listView = (ListView)view.findViewById (R.id.lst_view);
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter (getActivity (),R.layout.fragment_one,listData);
    listView.setAdapter (adapter);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onAttach (Context context) {
    super.onAttach (context);

    if(context instanceof  ListInterface){
        listInterface =(ListInterface)context;
        listInterface.getValue (listData);
    }else{
        throw new ClassCastException (context.toString ()+"mess ");
    }
}}
```

FragmentTwo:

```
public class FragmentTwo extends Fragment {

private ListView listView;

@Override
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate (R.layout.fragment_two,container,false);
    listView = (ListView)view.findViewById (R.id.lst_view_two);
    return view;
}

public void setValue (String [] value){
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter (getActivity (),R.layout.fragment_two,value);
    listView.setAdapter (adapter);
}}
```

ListInterface:

```
public interface ListInterface {

public void getValue (String [] s);}
```

i tried my codes it show

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
 FragmentTwo.setValue(FragmentTwo.java:27)
 MainActivity.getValue(MainActivity.java:31)
 FragmentOne.onAttach(FragmentOne.java:37)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the data in this way.

```
public static BuyerToyFragment newInstance(String yourText) {
        FragmentOne fragment = new FragmentOne ();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, yourText);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
```

NOw in fragmentOne you need to get data like this.

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            String myStringData = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        }
    }
```

and in your MainActivity you can set data like this.

```
// you can add string array as well. i dont remember the tag exactely. i its 
//like putStingArray() but you need to check it yourself

fragmentOne = new FragmentOne ().newInstance("Your data goes here");
```

**you need to do the same for fragment 2**

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the role of your list interface.

I don't really understand neither why you make your setValue and getValue call statically...

1/The easiest way is to store your list in your activity and then access it from the fragment, for exemple in onViewCreated.

Activity:

```
public String[] getMyList() {
    return mMyList;
}
```

You will also need to do the setter to set the list from another fragment.

Access your list from the fragment:

```
String[] listFromActivity = ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getMyList();
```

2/A cleaner way could be to pass your list as an argument to your fragment.

In activity :

```
FragmentOne frO = new FragmentOne();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putStringArray(mMyList, "my_list_key");
frO.setArguments(bundle);
```

In fragment :

```
String[] listFromActivity = getArguments().getStringArray("my_list_key");
```

The solution 1 is more easy if you want to update your list, if your list won't change the solution 2 is cleaner.